# Validate text box - data must be from auto complete (400 values)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to validate my form. I have added a text box with a auto complete. Sometimes people enter random stuff and clicks save.

However i want them to only use the auto complete data. so i was thinking if they enter something random it will give an error.

To do this I am finding difficulties and need some guidance.

This is how my current code looks like:

Textbox:

```
    <div class="genericFormText" id="test">Ticket SN:</div>
                        <div class="genericFormField">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Form.Ser_Num) 
</div>
```

Autocomplete code:

```
$("#Form_Ser_Num").autocomplete({
            source: "@Url.Action("SerialProdNumStockSiteAutoComplete", "Ajax")?stocksitenum=LW&model=" + $("#Form_Prod_Num").val(),

            minlength: 2,
            delay: 300,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.target.innerText = ui.item.label.split(',')[0];
                $("#Form_Ser_Num_Source").val(ui.item.label.split(',')[1]);
            }
        });
```

Save :

```
    var data = $("#ticketDetailsForm").serializeArray();

            $("#TicketDialog").load("@Url.Action("SaveInstallationTicketDetails", "SOP")", data, function () {
                //console.log("Saved suucessfully");
                alert("in save function");
```

backend code:

```
    public PartialViewResult SaveInstallationTicketDetails(InstallationTicketDetailsForm Form, string JobTypeSelected)
    {
        var viewData = new InstallationTicketDetails(Form.Call_Num);
        Form.Save(User.Identity.Name, JobTypeSelected, viewData.SendCompany, viewData.RelayWeight);

        viewData = new InstallationTicketDetails(Form.Call_Num);
        viewData.Form = Form;
        return PartialView("_InstallationTicketDetails", viewData);
    }
```

What is the best way for me to validate the text box to ensure no random data is added and only autocompelte data is selected, any idea or help would be very appreciated.

**is there something where i can do a if statement to see if the data is not equal to the auto complete then show an alert?**

Comment: Do you want something like [this functionality](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)?

Comment: the problem is there is like 400 different data, so drop drown will not be ideal, am thinking some sort of logic where it checks if the text box is same as the auto complete options.

Comment: When you only want to allow certain values, you should use a list box instead.

Comment: certain values as in 400. so it is not ideal to use list box. i want to validate the box so it matches the auto complete data but now sure how to do this.

Comment: is there something where i can do a if statement to see if the data is not equal to the auto complete then show an alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like this :

```
change: function( event, ui ) {
  if ( !ui.item ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i" ), valid = false;

    select.children("option").each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
        this.selected = valid = true;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if (!valid) {
      // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
      $(this).val("");
      select.val("");
      input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Also for more information and demo please [see this](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).Also you can see http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/j3AN7/

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what am looking for, now for the tricky bit - let me try combining the code.

Comment: @mali my pleasure...if it is helpful  to you please accept the anser

Comment: yes i will once i get it working. out of the 3 way you have shown which is the easiest to implement on my code do you think

Comment: All of them are easy...but depends on you @mali

Comment: i had a quick look at the js fiddle example, it says to use  source: validOptions - but in my autocomplete i already have a source "@url.action"

Comment: would you able to show me a working example based on my code please?

Comment: you have to create validOptions array of your autocomplete data in jquery or you can check on button click in the database and empty the textbox accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Just wondering , why you can't check if entered value exist in data? You can do it on client side. As your data is in array you can check if entered value exist in array. Or is there something i am missing?

Another way could be, You can create your own Custom Validation Attribute and then use this attribute in your model..

Your attribute would be like

```
public class DataExistanceAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var repo = new Repo(); 
            //Cast it to the data type, i am just casting it to int...
            var enteredValue = (int)value;
            // Code to check if the entered value exists in the database...
            if (reop.DataToCheck.Find(value) == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And then in your model

```
[DataExistance]
public string DataFieldToCheck {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use change event of autocomplete like below:

```
change: function(event,ui)
        {
        if (ui.item == null)
            {
               $("#your_input_box").val('');
               $("#your_input_box").focus();
            }
        }
```

Because what it is doing that is the entry is not made/chosen from auto complete ui.item will  be null. So you can easily come to know that user selected autocomplete entry or not and restrict random values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use typeahead.js. Refer to this [link](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/).

In the client side you can populate your 400 values using async ajax call to DB.

Then on the server side you can compare the selected user value with values from DB.
 So Here basically there will be 2 DB calls

- One for the client side & the other for server side for validation.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: auto complete works, i want something that validates the auto complete